# Counting match between two arrays at same index position and having non zero values

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays as below:

```
b = array([[1, 0, 1],
           [0, 0, 1]])

c = array([[ 0.5 ,  0.  ],
           [ 0.34,  1.  ],
           [ 0.  ,  1.  ]])
```

How to count matching values of two arrays based on same index value AND the element value of the array should non zero.  Here matching value is based on index of the element and not the exact value.

For eg. in the above matrices, my two arrays are row of b and corresponding column of c. If you see, 0.5 c[0,0] in c matches with 1 (b[0,0]) of b. The value doesn't match but since they are non zero values and present in the same position in the respective arrays (both present at 0th index), it should be counted. If the value is zero in either array position then it won't be counted.

For the above matrices, I should get 2 hits, because first row of b and first column of c has common non-zero elements at only one value: b[0,0] or c[0,0]. Similarly, the second row of b has one match with second column of c: b[1,2] or c[2,1]

I tried the following code, but it gives sum as 3 instead of 2. Because it is also counting the case where both the position have 0 as value and it matches that too. I want non zero value at the same position in two arrays.

```
sum=0
for x in range(b.shape[0]):
    sum+=np.sum((b[x,:]==0) == (c[:,x]==0))
```

I then tried this: this would first get the non zero indices of both the arrays and then compare. But it gives an error.

```
sum=0
for x in range(b.shape[0]):
    sum+= np.sum((np.nonzero(b[x,:]!=0)) == (np.nonzero(c[:,x]!=0)))


ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Why did you delete the previous version of this question instead of simply updating it appropriately?

Comment: updated the question. I deleted because i was not sure if someone putting it to close would get visibility or not

Answer (score 1):

Your critical problem is checking that the "non-zero" values are equal: you need an **and** here, not **==**:

```
    sum += np.sum((b[x,:]!=0) & (c[:,x]!=0))
```

This yields the desired result of **2**.

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([[1, 0, 1],
           [0, 0, 1]])

c = np.array([[ 0.5 ,  0.  ],
           [ 0.34,  1.  ],
           [ 0.  ,  1.  ]])

sum=0
for x in range(b.shape[0]):
    print "row/col", x
    print b[x,:]!=0
    print c[:,x]!=0
    sum+=np.sum((b[x,:]!=0) & (c[:,x]!=0))

print sum
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I tried this too and it works if I use any()

sum=0
for x in range(b.shape[0]):
    e=np.array(np.nonzero(b[x,:]!=0))
    f=np.array(np.nonzero(c[:,x]!=0))
    print e
    print f
    sum+=np.sum(e.any() == f.any())
                                    
sum

Comment: I have one addition to this. Instead of just counting 1 where there is a non zero same index position match, how to count (1/index position) in array c?. So basically wherever there is a match of non zero value at same index position between two arrays, add 1/index position of c array where match occured

Comment: Generate a vector with the needed Boolean values; you should be able to figure out how to sum 1/**N+1** for index **N** over the vector.

Comment: Didn't get that. I was thinking I can get the index array of non zero for both these. Then how to just get an array of matching indices. If I have that vector then i can sum that up as u said